# How to solve flutter app click delay to open issues?

Tags: flutter

when I click to open Flutter app it will delay a few seconds, and will show the info below, May I know what issue is this?

```
W/ResourceType(10910): Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f0b0000 which is invalid or in a cycle.

D/DeviceInfoPlugin(10910): Use TaskQueues.

D/InputTransport(10910): Input channel constructed: fd=82

D/ViewRootImpl@a281bcb[MainActivity](10910): setView = DecorView@58ddfa8[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false

V/InputMethodManager(10910): Not IME target window, ignoring

D/ViewRootImpl@a281bcb[MainActivity](10910): dispatchAttachedToWindow

V/Surface (10910): sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0

D/ViewRootImpl@a281bcb[MainActivity](10910): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 3213778944} changed=true

D/mali_winsys(10910): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1

D/OpenGLRenderer(10910): eglCreateWindowSurface = 0xc75bca00

D/SurfaceView(10910): BG show() Surface(name=Background for - SurfaceView - com.ifkm.ifkm/com.ifkm.ifkm.MainActivity@be7e266@0) io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{be7e266 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1280}

V/Surface (10910): sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
D/SurfaceView(10910): surfaceCreated 1 #8 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{be7e266 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1280}

D/mali_winsys(10910): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1

D/SurfaceView(10910): surfaceChanged (720,1280) 1 #8 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{be7e266 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-720,1280}

D/ViewRootImpl@a281bcb[MainActivity](10910): MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 720, 1280) ci=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 48 - 0, 0) or=1

D/ViewRootImpl@a281bcb[MainActivity](10910): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1

V/InputMethodManager(10910): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@99aa9a7 nm : com.ifkm.ifkm ic=null

I/InputMethodManager(10910): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus

D/InputTransport(10910): Input channel constructed: fd=91

D/ViewRootImpl@a281bcb[MainActivity](10910): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1280] new=[0,0][720,1280] result=0x3 surface={valid=true 3213778944} changed=false
```

This app is ok but after I run this command `git reset --hard HEAD~1` my Flutter app will delay opening when click on it.